# iOS Notification Service extension did not work

Tags: ios

I have encountered an issue: I added an 'interruption-level' field with the value of 'time-sensitive' to a remote notification request, and the notification was triggered successfully. However, the Notification Service app extension did not work. What could be the reason for this?

below is my push payload:

```
{  
   "aps":{  
      "sound":"default",
      "mutable-content": 1,
      "alert":{  
         "body":"this is a time sensitive push",
         "title":"Push Test"
      },
      "interruption-level":"time-sensitive"
   }
}
```

When I added this field: 'interruption-level':'time-sensitive', NSE was not called.

I hope that the NSE can capture remote notifications and modify them.

Comment: You should add more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @HalilOzel  Thanks for your reply ！I found the reason for the failure. It was because the server developers didn't set 'mutable-content' to 1.

Answer (score 0):

oh，Check with your server developers if '**mutable-content**': 1 was passed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).